# Implementing Satellizer angularJs app using c# asp.net 5 api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, satellizer, asp.net-core

I seem to have got to a certain step and now i am stuck, nothing is making sense.  I am not entirely clear on security/jwt and tokens in asp.net so my apologies if this is a stupid question.

On Satellizer github page (found [here](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer)) under **Login with oAuth2**, i am stuck on step 6, which says Authorization code is exchanged for access token.

I have setup my google application via google, i can login with it, and a request is sent back to my c# web api with the following properties

Code
ClientId
RedirectUri

Now how do i get an access token using the authorization code?  I want to do the same thing in the future with facebook and twitter logins, but thought i would start with google, so i know how everything works.

In my web api (using asp.net 5) i have setup openiddict by following this guide http://capesean.co.za/blog/tag/openiddict/

Am i missing something?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/carl09/satellizer/tree/master/examples/server/c%23-webapi2

Comment: did you find a way to do this?